# Adding an advert every x lines

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ads

Ok I seem to be running into a snag and not sure as to why

I created the ad code:

```
AdControl myad = new AdControl("test_client", "Image480_80", true);
myad.Width = 480;
myad.Height = 80;
```

Inside a loop later on I have

```
if (r % 3 == 0)
{
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(myad);
    r++;
}

TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
txt.Text = s.Name;

Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "btn" + a.ToString();
btn.Content = txt;
btn.Width = SCREENWIDTH / BUTTONSPERROW;
btn.Height = btn.Width;
btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush((App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color);
btn.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
btn.Click += btn_Click;
btn.Hold += btn_Hold;
btn.Tag = s;
btn.Margin = new Thickness((SCREENWIDTH / BUTTONSPERROW) * c, r * 150, 0, 0);

ContentPanel.Children.Add(btn);
//work out next position
if (c == BUTTONSPERROW - 1) { c = 0; r++; }
else { c++; }

a++;
```

everything worked until the ad line `ContentPanel.Children.Add(myad);` was added
Id I comment it out it all works and there's a gap left where It would be.
Given that the `ContentPanel.Children.Add(btn);` line works fine I'm baffled as to why the myad line isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add a new instance each time, not reuse the only one you have. The way you do it now will add "myad" the first time, and all subsequent times it will be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new `AdControl` inside the loop and add it like below

```
if (r % 3 == 0)
{

    AdControl myad = new AdControl("test_client" + r, "Image480_80", true);
    myad.Width = 480;
    myad.Height = 80;
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(myad);
    r++;
}
```